# MeasureText() - SizeF to inches

Tags: vb.net, dymo

I guess I don't know what search terms to use, this should be simple... I what to determine the width in inches of a string.

```
        Dim sSize As System.Drawing.SizeF
        Dim fFont As New Font("Arial", 12)
        sSize = Me.CreateGraphics().MeasureString(txtAddr.Text, fFont)
```

The units here are whatever the IDE is using. I'm not sure that is a constant value, if it is the conversion should be straightforward.

Any way, I want to convert the returned units to inches when the text is printed at 100% using the specified font. How do I do that?

---

Thanks Hans!

```
        Dim boxGraphics As Graphics = txtAddr.CreateGraphics()
        Dim sSize As System.Drawing.SizeF = boxGraphics.MeasureString(txtAddr.Text, New Font("Arial", 12))
        Dim iInches As Single = sSize.Width / boxGraphics.DpiX
```

---

Beginnings of DYMO LabelWriter 450 code for those that might be interested:

```
        ' project ref to DYMO.Label.Framework .net 3.5/4
        ' Imports DYMO.Label.Framework
        Dim olabel As Label
        olabel = Label.Open("H:\INFO\Forms\ADMIN\Dymo Labels\APCDAddress.label")
        olabel.SetObjectText("ADDRESS", txtAddr.Text) ' case sensitive
        olabel.Print("\\PC3090-117\DYMO LabelWriter 450 Twin Turbo")
        MsgBox("Printed")
```

I'll be adding code to deal with address text that maybe too large for the label, hence the OP. The DYMO layouts can be set to shrink to fit the text but that has practical limits when making address labels.

Comment: If this IDE is using font sizes in "pixels", then you may be getting a width in pixels as well. "The pixel" is not derived from any real world measurement system; to calculate a Real World width, you need to know the (real or assumed) ppi value as well.

Comment: Hence the OP - how do I, at runtime on a variety of PCs, come up with width in inches for a text string? I'm trying to figure out if I send an address to a label printer if the address text will fit on the physical label of a know size.

Comment: Hence my question.  Do you know in what units the value "12" is in your font change?

Comment: Divide by Graphics.DpiX

Comment: @HansPassant why don't you post that as answer?

Comment: It's not like he needs the points.... I posted the final below to close the OP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From @HansPassant: Divide by Graphics.DpiX

```
   Dim boxGraphics As Graphics = txtAddr.CreateGraphics()
    Dim sSize As System.Drawing.SizeF = boxGraphics.MeasureString(txtAddr.Text, New Font("Arial", 12))
    Dim iInches As Single = sSize.Width / boxGraphics.DpiX
```